# How can I write this directive without using element.on - not using jquery

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to write this directive without jQuery.

Inpired by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) I am trying to get rid of jquery where it is not needed or where I can do it another way . . .

```
 MyApp.directive('myCamera', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.on('click', function() {
                navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageURI)
                {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        ctrl.$setViewValue(imageURI);
                    });
                }, function (err) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('error', false);
                },
                //Options => http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera
                { quality: 50,
                  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
                })
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: use elm.bind instead of elm.on

Comment: @ganaraj set it as the answer to the question, it made the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the dependency on JQuery, you need to replace

```
element.on('click',fn(){});
```

with

```
element.bind('click',fn(){});
```

All the documentation for angular's jquery lite implementation is available under

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element